# Organizing folders and sub-folders in htdocs

Tags: xampp, absolute-path

I'm using windows 7 (64 bit).

If I place a site (index.php, other docs and other sub  folders [css, js, imgs etc] 
directly inside the htdocs folder (amongst the XAMPP folders) 
and view the site through localhost there is no problem.

If instead the site is placed in a subfolder of htdocs, C:xampp/htdocs/mysite,
and I try to view index.php all links (relative) to subfolders (eg images, css and js etc) stop working.

I obviously would prefer to use xampp for more than one site, so i want to have a sub folder in htdocs for each site.

Believe me I've been googling and I've looked at some 'solutions' (for example changing the httpd.conf for example, would mean changing it each time i want to view a different site....) but nothing has helped. What things should I be checking out?

Edits

LINKS FORMATTING

```
href="/css/homeAreaStyle111.css"

data="/svg/linkedbutton.svg"
```

Comment: you have to go through [absolute and relative urls](http://www.webdiner.com/webadv/begin/paths.htm)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your point, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you preceeding your links with a slash? Ie

```
    <a href=/page.htm>
```

If so those links will be pointing to the site root. Try replacing with ex

```
    <a href=page.htm>
```

or

```
   <a href=./page.htm>
```

Comment: What would this mean when the site goes live? I have to re-reformat all links?

Comment: Unless you are referencing documents from outside the site, you should be using relative urls, ie one of the variants from above. You are telling the web browser to fetch the documents from the current folder. If you trail with a slash, then you are telling the browser to go to the root of the domain and then fetch the file.

Comment: Sweet, changing from absolute to relative worked and required no additional structuring/coding between local and live. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have your website at `C:xampp/htdocs/mysite` then your links will look like:

```
href="/mysite/css/homeAreaStyle111.css"

data="/mysite/svg/linkedbutton.svg"
```

Comment: So the links would be invalid live? Best workaround would then to use a php variable? $url = /mysite; (localhost) $url =; (live)?

Comment: links won't be invalid live provided you create `mysite` directory under your website root..

Comment: Thanks, went with lairdpleng as it required less changes